# Access IBM Object Storage Aspera API in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, ibm-cloud

I am trying to implement the Aspera cloud object storage using ATS API in .NET.

Is there any way to retrieve the cloud API object to retrieve using C#?

While going with the [IBM documentation](https://github.com/IBM) there is only support for Java and python.

Comment: show what you tried!

Comment: @TusharWalzade, I didn't start the development. am in the initial analysis of the IBM cloud storage. could you share the Aspera ATS API documentation related to the C#.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the fllowing:

1. look at: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/asperalm#ibm-cloud-object-storage
   This will allow you to transfer to COS using command line and Aspera
2. analyze the code, it is relatively sumple (cos.rb)
3. use IBM Aspera "Transfer SDK" you can find here:
   https://developer.ibm.com/aspera
4. write your own code for the REST calls part, and use the Transfer SDK once you have built the "transfer spec" to start the transfer.